# Wix Installer Conditional UI for Command-Line

Tags: c#, user-interface, wix, installation, windows-installer

I want to create a Wix Installer with a UI, that can also be installed from command line for automated deployment testing, whilst also being the same installer that is used in the field.

Is there a way to enforce a conditional UI? i.e.: not show the UI if a command is entered? I could add conditions to the dialogs to not require interaction if certain properties are configured etc, but there must be an easier way?
Hope someone can help with this!
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Installer already supports silent installations.  [See: Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx)

An example of a silent installation would be:

```
msiexec /i example.msi /qn
```

Comment: I realised at some point this morning that msiexec had a super user type control over the gui so you are absolutely right, silent install would do it. The key aspect will be ensuring all properties etc, steps, can operate from command line. **a Further question:** what does silent mode do for listboxes/comboboxes/etc on a custom ui that would be displayed normally?

Comment: Silent installations completely omit the entire UI sequence.  None of that would ever happen.  That's why it's important to design and test an install to work silently also.  You do this by scheduling any custom actions to run in both UI and execute sequence and to function correctly.  You properties that are marked as Public and Secure to ensure a user can pass them at the command line during silent installation.